# Как скомпилировать 2 файла в C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

До этого писал программу в 1 листинге с расширением .cpp, начал читать книгу. Там отдельно создается файл с расширением .h как понял заголовочный с названием всех классов и их членами. Затем создается файл с расширением .cpp в нем расписываются все методы и тд. И создается 3 файл,  который уже компилируются с использованием файлов 1 и 2. Как их компилировать все вместе в Visual Studio, а не писать все в одной большой программе?

Comment: В `Visual Studio` если вы создаете пустой проект, то справа должны быть папки. Кликая пкм по папке `"Исходные файлы"`  вы можете создать `.cpp` файл, а в папку `"Файлы заголовков"` `.h` файлы. И просто `f5` жмете и у вас все автоматически будет собираться и компилироваться

Comment: @ПавелЕриков , спасибо, а если я создам консольное приложение, то такое возможно?

Comment: пустой проект и так запускается в консоли, но вообще да

Comment: имхо, использование солюшенов `visual studio` - плохой тон. Для проекта придется иметь `visual studio`, а она в добак только под винду. Что делать если ваш коллега программирует в другой ide? Все уважающие себя проекты имеют `make` и/или `cmake` скрипты для сборки (последний стал фактическим стандартом в сборке паректов)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch конечно, новичок, который только начал читать книгу о C++ (с его слов), сразу же пойдет читать и про cmake\make. А не научится работать в чем-то проще, для начала.

Comment: @SelfishCrawler новичек, который только начал читать книгу по с++ должен с компилятором научиться работать - вот что он должен делать. А разобравшись с компилятром следующий очевидный шаг - это make. cmake же идет за make - естественная цепочка, сам также изучал междупрочим

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch вы слегка заблуждаетесь. Чтобы собрать солюшн, достаточно иметь MSBuild, который лежит свободно на гитхабе и работает [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546121/how-to-install-msbuild-on-os-x-and-linux] на макоси и линуксе.

Comment: @gbg А этот MSBuild под MacOS/Linux он какой компилятор использует? Можно например ему сказать использовать CLang или GCC? Получается все настройки проекта MSBuild сконвертирует в соответствующие аргументы командной строки других компиляторов clang/gcc?

Comment: @gbg хм, не знал. Но сдесь возникает резонный вопрос: а если необходимо добавить для сборки еще один файл - как это сделать? Всмысле эти файл не читаемы, добавить как в make и cmake не получиться. Значит либо MSBuild должен иметь подобный интерфейс (решение не очень, так как он все-таки билдить должен, а не редактировать конфиг), либо это еще одно тула должна быть...

Comment: Формально, они в формате XML. С другой стороны, уж лучше все же использовать CMAKE, нежели завязываться на майкрософт и Моно.

Answer (score 1):

Хотя мой ответ немного не по теме, но решил поделиться опытом на всякий случай, для дополнительных знаний, опытом компиляции из командной строки.

Очень мелкие тестовые программки состоящие из 1-3 файлов, например олимпиадные задачки или задачки StackOverflow, можно компилировать быстрее и удобнее из командной строки, для этого один раз создаём такой командный файл `compile.cmd`:

```
@call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
@call cl /utf-8 /std:c++latest /Z7 /EHsc /D_WIN32 /D_DEBUG /Od /MTd %*
```

В этом командном файле я указал стандартный путь куда устанавливается Visual Studio 2019 Community, у вас возможно будет другой путь к вашей студии, и файлу `vcvars64.bat` внутри подпапок, так что это требует правки.

Дальше, как видно я указал `vcvars64.bat` - это для компиляции 64-битного приложения, если надо 32-битное то просто меняем на слово `vcvars32.bat`.

Также командный файл рассчитан на компиляцию отладочной (debug) версии, если нужно релиз (release) версия то просто меняем в командном файле `/D_DEBUG /Od /MTd` на `/GL /O2 /MT`, и если в релизе не нужна отладочная информация то ещё убираем флаг `/Z7`.

Далее используется этот командный файл элементарно, например для приложения с двумя исходными `.cpp` файлами будем просто вызывать:

```
compile.cmd main.cpp library.cpp
```

Указывать заголовочные файлы (`.h`/`.hpp`) в команде компиляции не обязательно, достаточно только `.c`/`.cpp` файлов. После вызова команды компиляции на выходе будет `.exe` файл.

Comment: Чем это быстрее, если у человека есть уже проект в visual studio, где компиляция 1-2-3-10000 файлов производится одной кнопкой?

Comment: @SelfishCrawler Я имею быстрее тогда, когда ещё проект не создан, ну чтобы не создавать с нуля под мелкую задачку. Смотрите, для каких задач я это имел ввиду. Например вот я иногда за день в StackOverflow решаю скажем 20-30 мелких задачек на С++. Каждая задачка это 1-3 мелких исходных файла, что в английском code snippet обычно называется, т.е. какой то маленький алгоритм. Так вот если бы я под все эти 30 задачек в день по проекту в вижуал студии создавал и настраивал, я бы и устал и много времени потерял, а так я из командной строки за секунду их компилирую и тестирую и отсылаю в ответ SO.

Comment: для этого есть онлайн компиляторы, ну а у меня есть заранее заготовленная песочница в вижуалке

Comment: @SelfishCrawler Например я работаю в консольном файловом менеджере [FAR](https://farmanager.com/), там отличный редактор с красивой раскраской всех языков и Python/C++ (на которых я пишу), из консоли удобно не выходить ни куда, ни в браузер, ни в вижуал студию, сразу в консоле и редактировать и компилировать и исполнять в одну команду. Так что я скорее ответ этот написал для таких же гиков и любителей консоли как я, мало ли пригодится.

Comment: @SelfishCrawler Ещё одно полезное применение моего ответа в том для тех кто хочет написать свой С++ сборщик. Я такой написал для нашей фирмы. Это Питон программа которая аналогичная CMake но очень простая и многопоточная, любую программу сложную можно описать в спец файле в пару строк, зависимости и т.п. Также компилируется как в мэйк только то что изменилось. Суть в том, что для таких создателей сборщиков как я ответ будет полезный чтобы знать точный полный набор флагов CL которые например я применяю у себя в сборщике (именно те что в ответе перечислил).

Comment: @Arty а у вас специально включена сборка с отладочными символами и без оптимизаций?

Comment: Вряд ли разумно писать подобные скрипты, когда уже есть make. При чем он кросплатформенный и стандартизированный

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch - дополню - и многопоточный

Comment: @gbg Да, у меня по умолчанию приведён пример именно для дебаг версии. Т.к. для тестов начальных всегда дебаг быстро компилируется и благодаря наличию отладочных символов также может вывести больше информации (например информативный стэк ошибки). Если вы почитаете текст моего ответа то там сказано, что это дебаг командник, и написано что сделать для релиза.

Comment: @gbg Кстати по поводу многопоточности - у меня как раз в моём небольшом скрипте для сборок всё учтено, и многопоточность, и кэширование, и билд только обновлённых файлов, и кроссплатформенность. Ну это конечно на любителей, просто многие крупные компании типа Гугла все 100% решений и утилит под себя с нуля переписывают, только очень популярные утилиты используют стандартные, в нашей фирме отчасти тот же подход.

Comment: @Arty - главное, чтобы мне не пришлось у вас работать. Потому что сравните размер своей "фирмы" и размер гугла, это раз. И сколько полезной работы вы бы могли сделать непосредственно по профилю работы фирмы, а не велосипедя стандартный инструмент - это два.

Comment: @gbg Написал я утилиту за день, там очень просто. А потом благодаря этой утилиты я сотни дней компилировал и создавал/описывал проекты за 10-20 сек, мне это очень нравилось, т.к. у нас по специфике работы очень много мелки программ/тестов и код-сниппетов, это всё требовало чтобы легко можно было создавать проект и зависимости за считанные секунды, в пару строк конфига. Более того специально даже для экспорта заказчикам написал простой конвертор моих проектов в несколько разных систем (Make, CMake, Bazel) в зависимости от запросов заказчика.

Comment: @Arty - так и где гитхаб с этим чудо-инструментом?

Comment: @gbg А, это всё выкладывается в доступ только если попросить директора и он даст разрешение код опенсорсить. Т.к. по умолчанию весь наш код это коммерческая собственность. Можно конечно сделать, но я уверен потом мне в гитхаб начнут сыпаться такие же замечания, что мол зачем ещё одна система. Но именно для нас она была реально очень полезная и очень простая в использовании.

Comment: Критика выгодна обоим сторонам - и вам и сообществу. Если ваш инструмент дейстивтельно так хорош, как вы его описываете, его возьмут в оборот. Если же он является очередным велосипедом, вы получите более точные знания о своей квалификации и научитесь чему-то новому. Потому что кумулятивные знания сообщества, как бы вы этому не противились, всегда будут превосходить ваши.